# Blinking cursor disappeared after setting EditText background to transparent

Tags: java, android

I have dynamically created EditTexts which I want to have a blinking cursor after creation, but I don't want them to have any bottom line. According to the recommendations I've found, I removed the line by setting the background of the EditTexts to transparent (editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent), as suggested by the docs). But now when the EditText is created, it has no blinking cursor, although I request focus for it (editText.requestFocus()). After making a check I saw that it is really focused.

I've tried everything I could find so far (for example, this: http://techfeeding.blogspot.com/2015/10/set-cursor-drawable-programmatically-in.html), but it didn't help to display the cursor - it appears only when you start to type, but this isn't the desired behavior. Somebody advised to set the input type, but it also didn't help: setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT). Setting isFocusable() and isFocusableInTouchMode() to true also gave no results.

The EditTexts have to be transparent, they can't have colored backgrounds, so changing the BG color to another one  isn't a solution.

When setting the background to transparent via XML (on another EditText), it works fine - the cursor is there after calling requestFocus(). But when doing the same programmatically the result is different. How can I achieve this through code?

My code in a custom View:

```
EditText edText = new EditText(getContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rootLayout.addView(edText, params);

params.leftMargin = Math.round(pointX);
params.topMargin = Math.round(pointY);
edText.setLayoutParams(params);

edText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
edText.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

**To set Custom EditText Background Width Blink Custom Cursor**, You Have to User 
 **android:textCursorDrawable** to Set Custom Cursor and  **android:background** for custom edittext.

See Below XML code i create two custom XML file one is used for background of EditText and another one is used for blink cursor.

**EditText XML Code**

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:hint="Enter Number 1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor_widht"
    />
```

**EditText Background XML Code**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:angle="270" />
<corners
    android:radius="30dp" />
<padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />
```

**EditText Cursor XML Code:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<size android:width="4dp" />
<solid android:color="#FF0910DD"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the above solution (inflated an xml EditText layout file via LayoutInflater), but when the view is created, the cursor still doesn't blink. The blue cursor appears only when the view is tapped. I found out that for some reason it doesn't receive focus even after calling requestFocus() on it. So, the only way I get a dynamically created EditText with a blinking cursor is still through my first code without any background modification, but then there's the bottom line present.

Comment: By Default Edittext Cursor use ascent color and if you give edittext background color as a ascent color then you can not see blink. so try to different color. i  use #FF0910DD this color as cursor color.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Use Field TO set Cursor in Your Edit Text.**

```
    LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
    rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout temp = new LinearLayout(this);
    temp.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    temp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));


    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1));
    editText.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.edittext_shape));
    temp.addView (editText);


    rootLayout.addView(temp);
```

**Above Code is for EditText Where i use my CUstom shape Instead oF Transprent You can choose as per your requirement.**

```
 try {
        Field f = MainActivity.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor_widht);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**With the help of Field You can set Cursor.**
Hope this Code is Work as per Your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this second block in my code today, but it didn't change anything. When I remove editText.setBackground, only then the cursor appears from the start. (By the way, the EditText is created on tap.)